# Asynchronous download of image in cocos2D

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I have used the CCSprite and giving image  which is present in the project using the function `spriteWithFile`. Now I want to download the image from the server and load it onto a CCSprite in cocos2D game scene. What are good alternatives. Please suggest.

I am using this code and its not working :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://50.62.138.228:6026/1370user.jpg"]]];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                 pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888
                                                  pixelsWide:50
                                                  pixelsHigh:50
                                                 contentSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    sprite_Temp = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
    sprite_Temp.position=ccp(432,273);
    [self addChild:sprite_Temp z:5];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start by searching for "Asynchronous image download" perhaps? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Sequence is:

```
 CCImage::initWithImageData(void* pData, int nDataLen, ...)
 CCTexture2D::initWithImage(CCImage* uiImage);
 CCSprite::initWithTexture(CCTexture2D* pTexture);
```

OR  in iphone

get data from any url

```
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sdufhs.com/img.png"]]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

you can get data in the form of data...

```
 NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

 CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithData:imgData
                                      pixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888
                                      pixelsWide:width2
                                      pixelsHigh:height2
                                     contentSize:size];

   CCSprite *sgfd = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
```

Comment: Hi. I am using ur code. I am able to make NSData. I pass NSData to texture, then when I create the sprite with that texture, its not working.. Nothing displays. ??

Comment: I have updated the code in the ques above. Can you please look into the code and tell mw, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [tutorial on creating a Webcam viewer with Cocos2D](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/01/download-modified-files-web-server-cocos2d-webcam-viewer/). The second part of the article explains asynchronous image downloads to speed things up. The example project is free to download with MIT License.